# How to find Covariance and Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability

In a game party there are 5 players. At a certain time each player is, independently of the others, currently playing a game with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ or not playing with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Whenever a player is playing a game, it loses calories with a rate P calories per second. The random variable X represents the total number of players who are playing a game at a certain time. The random variable Y represents the total rate at which calories are lost at a certain time.

I want to find the probability mass function $P_X(x)$ and covariance $Cov(X,Y)$ and show that the moment generating function of X is given by $\phi_x(s) = (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^s)^5 $.

I am doubting between if this is a Bernoulli or a Binomial problem. I'm thinking the latter is the correct answer.

So the PMF is then $\binom{5}{x}p^x(1-p)^{5-x}$  where $p = \frac{1}{2}$. $E[X] = 5*\frac{1}{2} = 2.5$.

I don't know how to continue, to find the $Cov(X,Y)$ I need to find $E[Y]$.

Can someone please show me how to find the $Cov(X,Y)$ and also how the moment generating function is obtained? I would appreciate it a lot !